# How to check if a file is locked without locking it using PHP

Tags: php, locking

I need to find a way, using PHP, to check if a file is locked without locking it. I came up with this code that works great, but it locks the file while trying to check if it's locked.

```
$file_lock5 = fopen("file_lock5.txt","w");

if (!flock($file_lock5,LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) {

    //file is locked

}
```

The problem with the code above is that I have to execute `fclose($file_lock5)` after it  (or let the process finishes) otherwise the file will get locked. I have dozens of other PHP processes already accessing this file (locking, writing, unlocking...) and I dont want to lock it just to check if it is locked because meanwhile other process might try to obtain the lock and it will get refused because the script above unnecessary locked it.

I just want to know if the file is locked, I dont need to write/read it after that - if that was the case I would then obtain the lock to write/read on it.

Any idea how can I make this using PHP?

Comment: If you don't need to use it, then why do you need to know if it's locked or not? Just trying to work out the use case

Comment: @ADyson I need to check if the lock is in place because if so, I know that another process is probably hanging for a while trying to write/read in it, and if that is the case I will delay the execution of any heavy load on the disk/cpu while the lock is in place.

Comment: You cannot check for a lock without acquiring the lock. Arbitrarily waiting on some process to stop using disk is just going to wind up with you soft-locking the application for no reason. The IO will happen when it happens, and if it's not happening fast enough then you need to address that issue by upgrading your storage, or caching more, or scaling out, or what-have-you.

Comment: @Sammitch easier said than done. I am using exactly this method to prevent me from quadrupling my server cost. This algorithm works fine for at least 3 years and without it, my disk and cpu usage gets crazy. I cant afford a more powerful server. That's why I am wondering if there is a way to check the lock because it would improve my performance even further because nowadays I acquire the lock to check it, and if this is unnecessary I can save some cpu cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Not going to complain a lot, but it's a tricky one - especially because `flock()` function isn't providing way to do this, and then it either acquires a lock or it's just waiting for one to be released.

With quick research, there are actually some solutions that you can consider:

1. By using `flock()` with Non-Blocking Mode (`LOCK_NB`): Because you're already using `LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB` in your code (which I don't say is wrong, but rather it's a good approach), the problem is, that it doesn't attempt to lock the file itself, now to avoid changing the lock state, you might need some other way and approach to this.
2. You can check file's last modified time: In case your processes are updating the file's last modified time, it might be worth checking its timestamps to infer if the file is being used, that could be an indirect method (but it's not 100% reliable in all cases).
3. You can use a separate indicator file or even flag: Now, actually the thing is that when a process does locking of main file, it **might** create or update a separator indicator file, also other processes could check the presence or status of that particular indicator file to decide if the main file got locked, the trick here is that this approach is requiring additional logic because it needs to figure out if the indicator file accurately reflects the lock status of the main file.
4. Database or Shared Memory for Lock indication: You can use shared resource like a dataabase or even shared memory (APCu in PHP - perhaps), that way you can record the lock status, where each process would update this shared resource in case and when it does acquiring or releasement the lock on the file.
5. Implementation of a custom locking mechanism: By relying on flock(), you're as written before purely relying on that function, it's possible to implement mechanism whcih is using database or file-based flagging, in that particular case processes can check the status without affecting it.

Now, all of these have advantages and downsides, as I said its tricky (complexity, reliability, portability...), and the approach is purely based on the specifics of your app's architecture and the environment (perhaps), you're running it on(now if you want tailored up answer for this, give us more context). Btw. In case of custom solution like using an indicator file or a shared resource, you'll have to be really, really careful when handling edge cases (perhaps, cleaning up the indicator if process is holding the lock terminates unexpectedly).

**UPDATE 1:**
When it comes to usage of `flock()` + combination of #3 suggestion, and work-around with it, your scenario would involve checking if `file_lock5.txt` is locked by another process and if it is, you will not perform certain actions, and you'd want to achieve this without locking the file yourself to avoid interfering with other processes, so you'd have to use a non-blocking `flock()` call to attempt locking and also use an indicator file `file_lock5.txt.lock" in order to track lock status, your code might look like this:

```
<?php

$file_path = "file_lock5.txt";
$lock_indicator_path = $file_path . ".lock";

// This function is checking if the file is LIKELY to be locked
function isFileLocked($file_path, $lock_indicator_path) {
    // Is .lock file existing?
    if (file_exists($lock_indicator_path)) {
        return true;
    }

    // We're trying to access it here:
    $file_handle = fopen($file_path, "c+");

    if ($file_handle === false) {
        // Not able to open it
        return true;
    }

    // Try to acquire an exclusive lock without blocking
    if (flock($file_handle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
        // we got lock, so we're releasing it imidietly!
        flock($file_handle, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($file_handle);
        return false; // The file was not locked
    } else {
        // Couldn't get the lock, assume the file is locked
        fclose($file_handle);
        return true;
    }
}

// Usage
if (isFileLocked($file_path, $lock_indicator_path)) {
    echo "The file is locked. Delaying operations...\n";
    // Perform actions for the locked state...
} else {
    echo "The file is not locked. Proceeding with operations...\n";
    // Perform your regular operations...
}
```

To give more of an idea here

- `isFileLocked` method/function is checking for existence of indicator file (`.lock`) - if file exists, we assume it's locked
- If it doesn't exist (`.lock`), the function tries to acquire an exclusive lock on actual file with `flock()` function, in a way that's non-blocking.
- If acquirng it is successful, its releasing it immediately, with indicator the file was not locked by another process
- If it can't acquire lock, it assumes that the file is locked.

You'd have to use this script consistently in all processes which are accessing your file `file_lock5.txt`, in order to maintain reliability.
You'd have to make sure that each process which is doing lock on your file, also creates `.lock` file.
You'd have to handle potential race conditions and edge cases (cleaning up indicator file in case your process crashes.

Why is it good? Because it's providing balance between checking the lock status without unduly locking file itself.

You could similary remove the part for the creation of `.lock` file and be focused mainly on the use of a non-blocking `flock()` call - but it doesn't eliminate the possibility of briefly locking the file, I don't know how much this is big problem, since the lock is acquired and released ALMOST instantly, therefore impact is minimal.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will see if another person finds a better way around using `flock` or  a simpler method, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: I personally really like #3. If you are working on `file.csv`, also just create `file.csv.lock`. There's a little more work, but it is also more obvious when debugging/investigating things. The lock file can even hold meta information that is specific to debugging, like what code specifically created it.

Comment: @Samul I just updated answer to provide combination of work-around with flock() and #3 method, which ChrisHaas suggested that he likes. By the way, I don't think anybody will find a better method, because the problem of checking if a file is locked in PHP without actually locking it and without using `flock()` is quite tricky, as PHP lacks a direct, built-in method to check file locks without actually attempting to acquire them.

Comment: @str1ng you did an awesome job and explanation! You are a wonderful person, thank you so much!