# PHP Timing of file update for file_get_contents

Tags: php

I am on linux and I am reading a file that gets updated every few minutes by another PHP script using file_put_contents.

I read the file doing:

```
$string = file_get_contents('/tmp/content.txt')
```

Say the file is large and it take 1000 milliseconds to write and my read happens at 500 milliseconds, will it serve the old file, the new file or the part of new file that has been written?

Comment: If you're worried about it, why not just space the read and write operations out a little bit more? If the updates are only every few minutes, you can at least spare a few seconds gap, I'm sure

Comment: Anyway, to answer the specific question - you might get an error if you try to read the file while another process is writing to it, because the process doing the writing will probably have locked the file.

Comment: The one process does not know when the other process is running, they are independant.  Is there any way to do the read other than file_get_contents that will check for a lock and then wait?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77822322/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-locked-without-locking-it-using-php might help you